# How to get back where user left off when navigated to a nested graph when navigated form option menu item?

Tags: android, android-menu, android-architecture-navigation

I have an app which requires multiple paired devices. From the flow of the app, there are multiple places where you can initialize pairing flow.

So I have the pairing flow as nested graph, and in *root graph*, I have a global action `pairing_action`. And inside the nested graph, I have another global action `finish_pairing`.

The problem is, when I call `finish_pairing` action from the pairing fragments, I always ends up at the main screen regardless from where I initiated the pairing flow.

But that's not what I want, **I want to get back to the screen where I initiated the pairing flow from** (where I left off when entering the pairing flow).

Code given below.

**navigation.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/start_fragment">

    <!-- Global action to start pairing -->
    <action android:id="@+id/pairing_action"
        app:destination="@id/pairing"/>

    <fragment ... />
    <fragment ... />
    <fragment ... />

    <!-- Nested pairing flow -->
    <navigation android:id="@+id/pairing"
        android:label="Pairing"
        app:startDestination="@id/pairing_fragment">

        <!-- Nested global action to finish pairing -->
        <!-- Should get to the fragment which initiated pairing! -->
        <action android:id="@+id/finish_pairing"
            app:popUpTo="@id/pairing"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

        <fragment ... />
        <fragment ... />
        <fragment ... />
    </navigation>
</navigation>
```

**nested pairing nav graph**

[image: Android Studio]

**EDIT 1:**

I get back to the main screen even when I press back button from the pairing flow.

Example: I get to the pairing screen like this:

```
main -> devices -> pairing -> enter code
```

Now when I call the `finish_pairing` global action from `enter code` screen (or press back 2 time), I want to return back to the `devices` screen. But I end up on the `main` instead.

**EDIT 2:**

This is the logcat when going from `devices` screen to `pairing graph`:

```
V/FragmentManager: Commit: BackStackEntry...
D/FragmentManager: mName=2-2131231057 mIndex=-1 mCommitted=false
...
D/FragmentManager: Operations:
D/FragmentManager: Op #0: REPLACE PairingFragment...
...
D/FragmentManager: Op #1: SET_PRIMARY_NAV PairingFragment...
...
V/FragmentManager: Run: BackStackEntry...
V/FragmentManager: Bump nesting in BackStackEntry... by -1
V/FragmentManager: Bump nesting of StartFragment... to 1
V/FragmentManager: Bump nesting of StartFragment... to 0
V/FragmentManager: Bump nesting of DevicesFragment... to 1
V/FragmentManager: Bump nesting of DevicesFragment... to 0
V/FragmentManager: remove: DevicesFragment... nesting=0

V/FragmentManager: add: StartFragment...
V/FragmentManager: Bump nesting in BackStackEntry... by 1
V/FragmentManager: Bump nesting of StartFragment... to 1
V/FragmentManager: Bump nesting of StartFragment... to 2
V/FragmentManager: Bump nesting of PairingFragment... to 1
V/FragmentManager: Bump nesting of PairingFragment... to 2
V/FragmentManager: remove: StartFragment... nesting=2

V/FragmentManager: add: PairingFragment...
V/FragmentManager: Added fragment to active set PairingFragment...
V/FragmentManager: moveto CREATED: PairingFragment...
V/FragmentManager: moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: PairingFragment...
V/FragmentManager: moveto STARTED: PairingFragment...
V/FragmentManager: moveto RESUMED: PairingFragment...

V/FragmentManager: movefrom RESUMED: DevicesFragment...
V/FragmentManager: movefrom STARTED: DevicesFragment...
V/FragmentManager: movefrom ACTIVITY_CREATED: DevicesFragment...
W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for DevicesFragment... not updated inline; expected state 1 found 2
V/FragmentManager: movefrom CREATED: DevicesFragment...
D/FragmentManager: Clearing non-config state for DevicesFragment...
D/FragmentManager: onCleared called for FragmentManagerViewModel{a60610c} Fragments () Child Non Config () ViewModelStores ()
V/FragmentManager: Removed fragment from active set DevicesFragment...
```

It seems that when navigating to `pairing graph`, backstack was popped (first `devices` screen then `start` screen) and then go to `pairing` screen.

Isn't it a bug? Why should global action pop backstack?!

I am using options menu items to get into the pairing flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use menu navigation heavily in my app. [NavigationUI supports it.](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer) But if you read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI?hl=en#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)) carefuly, there is this little remark:

> By default, the back stack will be popped back to the navigation graph's start destination. Menu items that have `android:menuCategory="secondary"` will not pop the back stack.

And this was the reason why entering pairing screens from devices screens "broke" the back stack.

So the solution was adding `android:menuCategory="secondary"` to the menu on devices screen, and it started working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a regular **action** from the nested graph to itself and set `popUpTo` nested graph itself.

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_pairing_nav_graph_self"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/pairing_nav_graph" />
```

**Design**

[image: nav graph]

**XML**

```
<navigation...
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentMain">

    <fragment...>
        <action.../>
        <action.../>
        <action.../>
    </fragment>
    <fragment...>
        <action.../>
    </fragment>
    <fragment...>
        <action.../>
    </fragment>

    <!-- nested graph -->
    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/pairing_nav_graph"
        ...>
        <fragment ...>
        <fragment...>
            <action.../>
        </fragment>

        <!-- action to the graph itself -->
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_pairing_nav_graph_self"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/pairing_nav_graph"
         />
    </navigation>
</navigation>
```

[Checkout: device-pairing branch in repo](https://github.com/kaushalyap/so-navargs/tree/device-pairing) for a working example.

Comment: So I still must have actions to and from each fragment that can use pairing and can't use glibal actions for that?

Comment: @Pitel does not this fix your problem?

Comment: Not exactly. I hoped I won't need to have separate actions for each screen which could start pairing.

Comment: @Pitel Have a take look at the updated post. You just need one global action (highlighted in the image with light blue)

Comment: Alright, I checked your repo and still has one big problem: imagine you can also get to the pairing flow from the main screen. How will you know which _back action_ should you call from `EnterCodeFragment`?

Comment: @Pitel so you want to go back to main screen if you went to pairing flow from the main screen?

Comment: Exactly! And maybe some ThirdScreen later... And I'd like to avoid having each back and forth transitions as separate actions, or also passing some values. I thought Navigation Component should handle it, but maybe it can't? :(

Comment: Actually it does handle, since fragment transactions are managed for you.

Comment: let move to chat